# multiple asp.net membership providers

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, wcf, membership-provider

I have created two custome membership providers that I would like to add to my web.config.  The first one would be the default that the asp.net application would use.  The second would be called by a WCF service that I have in the same application.

The providers in the membership section of my web.config looks like the following:

```
    <add name="SiteProvider" type="MyNameSpace.SiteProvider, MyNameSpace" ApplicationName="Si2" EnablePasswordReset="true" PasswordStrengthRegularExpression="(?=[\w$#_ ]{8,})(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[A-z])[\w$#_ ]*" ResetPasswordMinimumLength="8" ResetPasswordPattern="USL9SLU9SLU9SLLLL" ResetPasswordAllowDuplicateCharacters="false" />
    <add name="WCFProvider" type="MyNameSpace.WCFProvider, MyNameSpace" ApplicationName="Si2" EnablePasswordReset="true" PasswordStrengthRegularExpression="(?=[\w$#_ ]{8,})(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[A-z])[\w$#_ ]*" ResetPasswordMinimumLength="8" ResetPasswordPattern="USL9SLU9SLU9SLLLL" ResetPasswordAllowDuplicateCharacters="false" />
```

I receive the error "Item has already beed added.  Key in dictionary: 'SiteProvider'  Key being added: 'SiteProvider'" any time I browse to the site.

This doesnt make sense to me sense they have unique names.  If i remove the second provider the site is browseable.

Any help on adding this second provider would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to move the webservice into a different project.

Also, make sure you call `<clear/>` before adding providers and include a default one...

```
<membership defaultProvider="Siteprovider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SiteProvider" type="MyNameSpace.SiteProvider, MyNameSpace" ApplicationName="Si2" EnablePasswordReset="true" PasswordStrengthRegularExpression="(?=[\w$#_ ]{8,})(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[A-z])[\w$#_ ]*" ResetPasswordMinimumLength="8" ResetPasswordPattern="USL9SLU9SLU9SLLLL" ResetPasswordAllowDuplicateCharacters="false" />
        <add name="WCFProvider" type="MyNameSpace.WCFProvider, MyNameSpace" ApplicationName="Si2" EnablePasswordReset="true" PasswordStrengthRegularExpression="(?=[\w$#_ ]{8,})(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[A-z])[\w$#_ ]*" ResetPasswordMinimumLength="8" ResetPasswordPattern="USL9SLU9SLU9SLLLL" ResetPasswordAllowDuplicateCharacters="false" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

You could try the solution in this forum post: http://forums.asp.net/p/1112089/1714276.aspx

Have you tried putting a separate web.config file in the webservice folder? I doubt that it will work, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Daniel, I do have this in a seperate project but I am publishing it out into the same directory because I would like it to share the resources of the web application.  The code that you have is exactly what I have and get the error message expalined above.  The link you provided doesnt give me quite what I want.  I thought I would have the ability to add the second provider and point the WCF service to it all in the web.config without creating any code.  Is this possible?

Comment: Tht could be your problem. I think you should publish your webservice project to a sub-directory of your site. Set it up as a virtual directory in IIS and enable it for webservices.

Comment: So is it not possible to add more than one provider per application?  It seems like I have seen other people doing it like these guys.  http://www.sitefinity.com/help/developer-manual/implementing-multiple-membership-providers.html

Comment: I have had a look, and there seems to be a few examples like that one. So it must be possible. And the MSDN docs say you can, but helpfully doesn't show you how. Could it be that you are missing a connectionStringName from you provider settings?

Comment: The original provider never had a connection string name as this is handled in the code of the custom provider that is configured via enterprise library.  I am clearly missing something that seperates the two, but have not discovered what it could be.

Comment: I figured out the problem.  In the code the Name property of the custom membership provider was overridden and hardcoded to a string.  I needed to override it in my new class and have it produce a string that was different from the first one.  Thanks Daniel for your help.